# Winforms MDI distortion of labels

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

I have a winforms app which I have placed my own custom labels on using the following class

```
public class LabelWithBorder : Label
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        ColorMe(e);
    }

    private void ColorMe(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Color myColor = Color.FromArgb(104, 195, 198);
        Pen myPen = new Pen(myColor, 1);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(myPen,
        e.ClipRectangle.Left,
        e.ClipRectangle.Top,
        e.ClipRectangle.Width - 1,
        e.ClipRectangle.Height - 1);
        base.OnPaint(e);
    } 
}
```

The resultant LabelWithBorder simply has a border with colors to match my clients own literature / website etc.  The picture below shows (on the left) how it should / and does initially look like.
However the issue I have, is that whenever one window is dragged over another, the labels become distorted as per the picture on the right.

[image: LabelWithBorder]

Can anyone advice what is causing this distortion and how I should rectify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works and code is simple:

```
private Color myColor = Color.FromArgb(104, 195, 198);
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, ClientRectangle, myColor, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
    base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using double buffering as shown here:
https://web.archive.org/web/20140811193726/http://bobpowell.net/doublebuffer.aspx